# install pymc for ubuntu 14.04 fails in docker container, works on mac os

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.5

```UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 5125: ordinal not in range(128)

Reading fortran codes...

````
Reading file 'pymc/flib.f' (format:fix,strict)```
````

Comment: installs on aws EC2 instance with ubuntu 14.04.05

Answer (score 0):

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Assuming US locale, try running these commands before installing.

Comment: not allowed even as root in the docker container - line 3 fails
```
root@e702a4d7c0a4:/home# export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```
and same fail with pip3 install pymc

Comment: From what I can understand of the github setup.py file it seems that setup is trying to build from the installed libraries rather than downloading packages - and fails to find & compile locally.
Note that this is only in docker images.